# How to assign an object in a list to a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, oop, typeerror

I have  a list  that store `User` objects:

```
profiles_catalog = []
```

and the 'User' object:

```
cont = 1

class User:

    def __init__(self, name, password):
        global cont

        self.registry = cont
        self.name = name
        self.password = password
        self.liked = []
        self.matches = []

        cont += 1

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'Registry: {self.registry}, Name: {self.name}, Password: {self.password}, Liked_list: {self.liked}, matches: {self.matches}'

    def __dict__(self) -> dict:
        return {'Registry': {self.registry}, 'Name': {self.name}, 'password': {self.password}, 'Liked list': {self.liked}, 'matches': {self.matches}}

    @property
    def call_name(self) -> None:
        return self.name

    @property
    def call_password(self) -> None:
        return self.password

    @property
    def call_liked_list(self) -> None:
        return self.liked

    @call_liked_list.setter
    def model_like_profile(self, liked_user) -> None:
        self.liked.append(liked_user)
        return f'{liked_user.name} got liked'

    def see_matches(self) -> None:
        return self.matches
```

This is supposed to be a dating app, as tinder or something, that show random profiles to user and it should be able to like profile or keep seeing other profiles.

To do that, I write functions `show_random_profile()` and `main_like_profile()`:

```
def show_random_profile():

    displayed_user = profiles_catalog[randint(0, len(profiles_catalog) - 1)]
        
    return displayed_user
```

and

```
def main_like_profile(control_user, displayed_user):
    
    liking_user = control_user
    liked_user = displayed_user
    
    liking_user.model_like_profile(liking_user, liked_user)
    print('User liked!')
```

but I'm keeping getting TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Lucas\Documents\LUCAS\programacao\python\meus_projetos\twindder\controller.py", line 140, in <module>
main()
  File "c:\Users\Lucas\Documents\LUCAS\programacao\python\meus_projetos\twindder\controller.py", line 109, in main
main_like_profile(control_user, displayed_user)
  File "c:\Users\Lucas\Documents\LUCAS\programacao\python\meus_projetos\twindder\controller.py", line 34, in main_like_profile
liking_user.model_like_profile(liking_user, liked_user)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

The way I see, the problem is that a `list` object it is been assign to a variable that should take `User`, is that right?

If so, how can I assign to `displayed_user` a random `User` object stored in `profiles_catalog`?

Or there is any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: 1) In your own words, where the code says `@call_liked_list.setter`, what do you think that means? What does that imply about the `model_like_profile` method that is thus decorated? Do you see why this causes a problem for the code `liking_user.model_like_profile(liking_user, liked_user)`, where the error was reported? 2) Do you understand how method calls look normally, and the purpose of `self`? Where the code says `def model_like_profile(self, liked_user)`, how many parameters *aside from the instance* are expected? So, how should it be called?

Comment: If the code for the User class comes from someone else, then there is a bug in it, and you should file a bug report - if you copied and pasted it e.g. from a tutorial, make sure you have done so correctly. Better yet, type it out yourself while following the tutorial, so that you understand what the code means as you go along. If the class is your own work, then these problems are simple typos - if you know how to write that kind of code, then you should also know how to spot these kinds of problems. Either way, the question is not suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please also see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some hints on tracking down problems. "the problem is that a 'list' object it is been assign to a variable that should take 'User', is that right?" Specifically, it means that `liking_user.model_like_profile` was a `list`, rather than a method. That happens because of the mis-placed `@property` decorator. If the problem were `liking_user` itself being a `list` (instead of a `User` instance), then the error would be an `AttributeError` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code, you define the `model_like_profile` method with the decorator `@call_liked_list.setter` applied to it, where `call_liked_list` is a property. This makes `model_like_profile` also refer to the same `call_liked_list` property. So, the line:

`liking_user.model_like_profile(liking_user, liked_user)`

... is equivalent to `liking_user.call_liked_list(liking_user, liked_user)`, which is equivalent to `liking_user.liked(liking_user, liked_user)`. Since `liking_user.liked` is a list, this line of code attempts to call a list as if it were a function, hence the `TypeError`.

Keeping the `User` class as you've written it, to access the functionality defined in `model_like_profile`, you could change from:

`liking_user.model_like_profile(liking_user, liked_user)`

to:

`liking_user.model_like_profile = liked_user`

Although this use of a property setter for adding to a list is generally not good practice - a property setter is usually used for assigning a new value, not adding to a list. Also, it is good practice for the property setter's method name to be the same as the getter's method name:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = 1

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        self._value = value
```

Comment: There are at least two presumable typos in the code: 1) there's a decorator being used for a setter that hasn't actually been written, so that it's being applied to an unrelated method; 2) the call to that method has a redundant parameter. Both of these are things that OP should be able to figure out by applying [standard debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), assuming that OP actually wrote the code in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, Oli. So, i thought 'model_like_profile' was set as a function, but in fact it was a list. I'll study more about oop and getters and setters.

Comment: Karl Knechtel, thank you for you 'standard debugging techniques', i'll read that. And yes, it was me that wrote that. As said, i'll learn more about oop and getters and setters to not mistake again.

Comment: @LucasRocha You're welcome! Just to clarify, `model_like_profile` was not itself a list, but was the getter for the `call_liked_list` property, making `liking_user.model_like_profile` evaluate to a list.